# Rails uses older version of jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I just upgraded my Rails 3 app to 3.1. My jquery-rails gem's version is 1.0.11, the up to date one, yet when I check out the application.js, the file that "//= require jquery", it still shows that the jquery used is stuck at 1.5. Does anyone have an idea to why this is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a older version of the actual jQuery files.

Run `rails generate jquery:install` and it should download the latest.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same issue but that didn't work. Running

`rails generate jquery:install`

is deprecated if you are running 3.1

> You are using Rails 3.1 with the asset pipeline enabled, so this generator is not needed.
>                 The necessary files are already in your asset pipeline.
>                 Just add `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` to your app/assets/javascripts/application.js
>                 If you upgraded your app from Rails 3.0 and still have jquery.js, rails.js, or jquery_ujs.js in your javascripts, be sure to remove them

I really can't see where jquery 1.5 is coming from.
My public/ has no js files
And have jquery-rails (1.0.19) installed (inspecting the gem folder one finds jquery 1.8!)

Cheers,